# Change how the volume scales? (The loudness of the sound at 100% volume)

Tags: sound, volume-control

Bit of an odd question here. Everything I have found is trying to make 100% volume louder, but on my speakers, 100% volume is *deafening*, so I have keep my volume bar about 20-30%. I want to allow allow for finer control at the lower volume as if the new "100%" is the same as the current 20-30%, the new graduations would be finer. Is this possible?

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running unity.

Comment: Supposed you use `pulseaudio` (PA) based on `ALSA`, and your volume control manages the default output of PA, you can call `alsamixer` from the command line, select your default output, and reduce the volume of the respective channel (that only works for analog devices; you cannot modify digital output channels like SPDIF or HDMI).

Comment: @ridgy This seems to only be editing the current volume of the different channels. While this does give finer control, what I was looking for is to make the unity sound menu "100% volume" actually a fraction of what it currently is. If you need more clarification, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `paprefs` command. In the "PulseAudio Preferences" window, goto "Simultaneous Output" and check the checkbox "Add virtual output device...". Close the window.

Run `pavucontrol`. In "Output Devices" select "Show: All Output Devices" (if not already selected). Make the virtual device "Simultaneous output to..." your default device (click on the green button on the right). Now your volume controls should work on this device.

Set the output level of your physical output device to 30% or whatever fits your needs.

If everything is correct, now the output volume control should be finer, as 100% of the default "simultaneous output" should be the 30% of your physical device.

If your PA database has remembered the (physical) output device for some applications, you might have to change that in the "Playback" section of `pavucontrol` when your application is running.

Remark: This is working for 16.04 with xfce4 volume control. Maybe you have to manually modify something in unity to have your volume controls modifying the PA default. You could also play around a bit with `pavucontrol` to see what can be done, especially with virtual devices.

**Edit:**

Usually, after having checked the item in `paprefs`, and reboot, the virtual output device should be displayed. If you cannot (or don't want to) reboot or 
if the output device "Simultaneous output..." is not listed, maybe the corresponding PA module "[module-combine-sink](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index11h3)" is not loaded. You can check with `pacmd list-modules`; there it should be shown like

```
$ pacmd list-modules
26 module(s) loaded.
.
.
    index: 26
    name: <module-combine-sink>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Combine multiple sinks to one"
        module.version = "8.0"
```

(your configuration and therefore the numbers may vary).

Ifit is not listed, you can load the module with

```
$ pacmd load-module module-combine-sink
```

It then should be visible to the output tab immediately.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the creation of the virtual device. It seems that `pavucontrol` isn't picking it up. Screenshots: http://imgur.com/a/PrYX5 as you can see, all that is listed is the hardware sound cards. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a different way to create virtual outputs that might work as well?

Comment: I did edit my answer - please test the advice.